# Nagle's Algorithm, ACK Delay and Rlogin echo

Tags: algorithm, networking, tcp, nagle

I was suggested to ask here too, since specific questions about protocols are on-topic, but in case anyone is interested the question also has a small bounty on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/796788/nagles-algorithm-ack-delay-and-rlogin-echo).

I'm reading about TCP data flow, *Delayed ACK* and *Nagle's Algorithm*.

So far I understand that:

1. The *Delayed ACK* implementation on TCP creates a delay on the acknowledgement of segments received to give the opportunity for the application to write some data along with the acknowledgement, thus avoiding sending an empty ACK packet and contributing to network congestion.
2. The *Nagle's Algorithm* implementation states that you can't send a small TCP segment while another small segment is still not acknowledged. This avoids the traffic being loaded with several *tinygrams*.

On some interactive applications, like Rlogin for instance, *Nagle's Algorithm* and *Delayed ACKs* can "conflict":

Rlogin sends the keyboard input to the server as we type them and some keys (like **F1**) generates more than one byte (**F1** = Escape + left bracket + M). Those bytes can be sent in different segments if they are delivered to TCP one by one.

The server doesn't reply with an echo until it has the whole sequence, so all the ACKs would be delayed (expecting some data from the application). The client on the other hand, would wait for the first byte acknowledgement before sending the next one (respecting the *Nagle's Algorithm*). This combination ends up resulting in a "laggy" Rlogin.

The `tcpdump` of the **F1** and **F2** key being sent on a Rlogin is represented below:

```
    type Fl key
1   0.0                 slip.1023 > vangogh. login: P 1:2(1) ack 2
2   0.250520 (0.2505)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 2:4(2) ack 2
3   0.251709 (0.0012)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 2:4(2) ack 4
4   0.490344 (0.2386)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 4:6(2) ack 4
5   0.588694 (0.0984)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: . ack 6
    type F2 key
6   2.836830 (2.2481)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 4:5(1) ack 6
7   3.132388 (0.2956)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 6:8(2) ack 5
8   3.133573 (0.0012)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 5:7(2) ack 8
9   3.370346 (0.2368)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 8:10(2) ack 7
10  3.388692 (0.0183)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: . ack 10
```

Now the doubt: Even though the page I read states that the server doesn't reply with an echo before it has the whole key sequence, the packets captured through `tcpdump` shows that the keys are being echoed on their respective ACKs (the first reply is 2 bytes long because the echo from *ESC* is two characters - caret + left bracket).

**If data is being sent from the application to TCP (the echo response) why are the ACKs being delayed?** According to what was stated, about the server **waiting the full sequence before echoing it**, wasn't the ACKs supposed to contain no echo up to the last ACK, that would contain the whole sequence echo?

**EDIT:**
Here is the output of `tcpdump` for the modified Rlogin, without the Nagle's Algorithm (TCP_NODELAY flag):

```
        type Fl key
1   0.0     slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 1:2(1) ack 2
2   0.002163 (0.0022)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 2:3(1) ack 2
3   0.004218 (0.0021)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 3:4(1) ack 2
4   0.280621 (0.2764)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 5:6(1) ack 4
5   0.281738 (0.0011)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: . ack 2
6   2.477561 (2.1958)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 2:6(4) ack 4
7   2.478735 (0.0012)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: . ack 6
        type F2 key
8   3.217023 (0.7383)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 4:5(1) ack 6
9   3.219165 (0.0021)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 5:6(1) ack 6
10  3.221688 (0.0025)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: P 6:7(1) ack 6
11  3.460626 (0.2389)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 6:8(2) ack 5
12  3.489414 (0.0288)   vangogh.login > slip.1023: P 8:10(2) ack 1
13  3.640356 (0.1509)   slip.1023 > vangogh.login: . ack 10
```

It can be noticed on segment 4, the ~0.2ms delay, even though Nagle's Algorithm is turned off (so all the special key bytes arrive together and can be processed together). On segment 6 we cannot identify the ~0.2ms delay because the server takes a while to reprocess and repacket the retransmission of some lost segments, but this delay is above 2s.

On the **F2** key example, on segment 11 we can also notice the ~0.2ms delay. We can't identify it on segment 12 because it was probably sent right after segment 11.

This does indicates that @MattTimmersans answer is right, and it could be that the book makes a misinterpretation of the segments delay. They could be indeed a characteristic of the network medium instead of the ACKs being delayed because of data not being sent down to the TCP stack.

Reference:
http://people.na.infn.it/~garufi/didattica/CorsoAcq/Trasp/Lezione9/tcpip_ill/tcp_int.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ACKs in segments 2,4,5,7 come with data, they are not delayed ACKs (weren't initiated by the ACK timer elapsing).

I believe the 0.25s delays associated with those are just the round trip time between hosts.  I notice that this data was logged in 1993.  If I remember correctly, I think a 250ms ping was not uncommon in those days.

If the tcpdump were run on `vangogh` instead of `slip`, it looks like it would see the echo coming quickly after the `ESC` and `[M` packets.

The example shows that Nagle's algorithm can suck even without ACK delay, because it adds an extra round-trip time to the exchange.

Comment: It makes sense, the book is a bit misleading in this topic if this is the case. Taking a look at the `tcpdump` output of the same example on a Rlogin with Nagle's Algorithm disabled, it seems that there's also this >0.2ms delay on the servers answers, so it probably is the RTT of the connection indeed. I'll take a better look once I get home and post the output of the version with TCP_NODELAY on the question.

Comment: I just edited the question to have the output of `tcpdump` on the modified Rlogin connection (without Nagle's Algorithm). After giving it some thought I believe your answer is right.
It does imply that the book is wrong on this particular chapter though, but that's a possibility, specially since for the last few months while I had this problem I couldn't find any other explanation for a delayed ACK to timeout with the echo character being sent.

Comment: I almost forgot. I was going to close the ServerFault question to respect the no-crossover questions rule, but I can't delete questions with a bounty. So if you have an account on ServerFault and wants to claim the bounty, I'll accept you answer there aswell. The [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/796788/nagles-algorithm-ack-delay-and-rlogin-echo) has been there since August 14th.

Comment: @IanC  Thanks for the consideration, but I don't have an account over there.  Cheers